# Spring Security to Validate login RestAPI

Tags: spring, security, rest

I know this question asked many times but I did not get answer that I required.

I want link that can help me to create a spring security framework, In which I donot whant login form validation.

It should be done by login RestAPI. I just hit url like-

```
http://localhost:8080/login
```

post request containing username and password and it return json response with sucess or failure status

if sucess I would be able to hit secure API Requests.

Comment: This is basically a standard spring-sec form based login (because form based login is nothing more then posting username and passwd to some url) combined with two proper templates returning json instead of html for the success and failure cases. Could you elaborate on the part(s) you are having problems with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using spring and spring security since 1 and half year with spring security to develop rest API I use below technique for user authentication
Follow below steps

1. Allow to access http:// localhost:8080/login for all user
2. User will pass username and password in body
3. Authenticate user with database entry
4. create access token and send back to response
5. using this access token user with interact with secure API.

I will provide source code if you need.

Comment: Thanks HitestR can you please sent me your code will give me more idea. As per your comment you are login via form but I am using RestAPI to login as well

Comment: I am using API for login I pass username and password in Json format.
I have to write code i will provide my github link before tomorrow.

Comment: Great! I will wait for your github link :)

Comment: Hello Anupam here I am providing you my github link to how to protect rest API using AccessToken
https://github.com/HiteshR90/RESTSpringSecurity
You can modify code as per you need.

Comment: Hi Hitesh,
Thanks for your code it's working fine when I am using <intercept-url.../> now I want to add method level security using @Secured annotation but it's not working with that code I have added <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/> in spring-security.xml file

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try with Basic Authentication. I believe Rest services are mutual contract between the consumer and provider, so re design your service to access the basic auth header. Your client need to pass the base64 encoded value of username:password, Your service should get the header value and decode you will get the original data back, Check against your backend storage (Ldap or DB).

More about basic authentication . [BasicAuthentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)